# How to jump from one screen to another and clear all other screen from stack in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, mobile-development, react-native-navigation-v2

I have an application where I have a tab screen and few screens.
From tab I navigate in order screen 1 -> screen 2 -> screen 3 .
From screen 3's button click, I want to open screen - 4 i.e listing screen and on backpress I want to navigate agin tab screen.

I dont want to reset full stack using `props.navigation.reset({index: 0,routes: [{name: "home"}],});`, also number of navigating screen between tab screen and screen 4 is not fixed so I can't use `props.navigation.pop(3)` also.

Can anyone guide me, how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be ok if you have a reset on tab change?

Comment: you can use `localStorage` to `setItem()` `getItem()` `removeItem()` here

Comment: @yesIamFaded when I open screen 1 , tab is not visible so I can't access tabs to reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve above navigation.

```
props.navigation.popToTop();
```

This will remove all screen from stack except main screen.
Hope this helps others!!